# Can a transceiver IC be used only in Tx or Rx mode, indefinitely?

Tags: rf

I am considering using a transceiver IC (S2LP [datasheet [1](https://www.st.com/en/wireless-connectivity/s2-lp.html)) as a receiver only.

I think it should be okay to do so but I wanted to confirm. Is there any reason why it should not be used only in Rx mode without using its Tx mode?

Comment: What does the data sheet of the I C say?

Comment: it doesn't say anything about operating only in one mode. It does say that one can only operate in Tx or Rx mode at a time, as it is a half-duplex system.

Comment: If you share a link to the data sheet, we will be able to help you much more than is we just have to guess what kind of chip you are using.

Comment: I have added the link to datasheet now.

Answer (score 0):

As it is a transceiver it can transmit and receive, but there is not reason for it should not be able to be used for only one of these.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can use a transceiver to only receive or only transmit.

In your particular case, I think it is only possible in a limited way.

The datasheet for the S2LP has the implicit assumption that you will use it to transmit and receive - it doesn't mention using it only for one or the other.

Most of the data transmission protocols it mentions also seem to assume that the receiver will send ACK packages back to the transmitter to acknowledge receipt.

The one exception that I can find is the "STack" packet format, which allows you to specify a "NO_ACK" bit.  "NO_ACK" means that the transmitter doesn't expect an acknowledge from the receiver.

It really looks to me like the only way to use the S2LP as a receiver only is to the "STack" data format and set the "NO_ACK" bit in the data packets on the transmitter side.

Comment: thanks for the response, but  when one does send the data via GPIO/Directly via Tx FIFO the internal packet formation blocks are disabled and it should work as Tx/Rx only.